# How do I close a content page and continue to the MainPage?

Tags: c#, shell, maui

I'm writting a .NET Maui application with a shell that currently has two pages. The main one I'm calling PassInfo and the second one I'm calling NewDb.

my App.xaml.cs file looks like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
  public string _dirVal { get; set; }
  public App()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new PassInfo();
  }

  protected override void OnStart()
  {
    base.OnStart();

    var dbList = new List<string>();
    dbList = GetDB();

    if (dbList.Count == 0)
        MainPage = new NewDb(true);
  }
  
  private List<string> GetDB()
  {
    // Omitted code that returns a list of any
    // found database files.
  }
}
```

When I run the app like this, I have no database files, so the NewDb page opens no problem. On this page I have a save button that creates and saves a database file.

What I would also like it to do is close NewDb page and then open the PassInfo page.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the MainPage with a `new PassInfo()`? You might want to look into navigation pages for moving around an app without a shell.

Comment: You mean you use a [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/create?view=net-maui-8.0). But I didn't see that. From the question, ```PassInfo``` and ```NewDb``` are two ContentPage not shell page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you say you are using shell right?

1. This here is not shell:

   MainPage = new PassInfo();

Remove it, return the default:

```
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

2. Go to MauiProgram.cs, and inject all your pages as transient. Do not use manual construction of pages, make use of the dependency injection.
3. Go to AppShell.xaml, and add your separate pages, as separate ShellItems. Set the route properties to the page names.

!!!Do NOT double register the routes in the AppShell.xaml.cs!!!

4. When navigating use "//PageName". This will clear your navigation stack and replace it with the other page.

This is now possible, because you registered them as separate ShellItems. The first one is your entry point.

Done. Not a single "new ()" used.